# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel. I have still not been able to figure out how to do this. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
import keep_alive
import discord

client = discord.Client()

channel = client.get_channel('ID'`enter code here`)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await channel.send('hello')


keep_alive.keep_alive()

client.run('ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_channel` won't work where you have it because the bot hasn't connected to discord yet (that happens during `run`). When the bot connects, it will build internal caches of all the things it's aware of (members, guilds, channels, etc.).  Those caches are what the various get methods use, but since the caches are empty those methods return `None`.

Instead, you can either get the channel in the `on_message` every time, or use a global variable in the `on_ready`:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        channel = client.get_channel(1234)
        await channel.send('hello')
```